# using the below code . why cant i set or add flags and expunge the mails permanentley using their UIDs in imap-node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, imap

let emailUid = [28276,28277,28278,28275];

```
await imap.openBox("[Gmail]/All Mail", false, async function (err, box) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("box opened",box.name);

  //  new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            // Mark the email as deleted
            let flags= ['\\Deleted']
            imap.setFlags(emailUid, flags, async function (err) {
              if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                //reject(err)
              } else {
                console.log('Flags added to the emails:', emailUid);
                // resolve()
                imap.expunge();
              }
            });
          // })
});
await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
 imap.expunge(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Expunge operation completed successfully.');
    resolve()
  }
})
});
```

connection to IMAP is successful .then the console logs in expunge is printed first then the log in setflags is printed.
finally , flags are not set to the mail and expunge operation is not completed when seen in the gmail

Comment: Please do not share pictures of your code. Instead, please copy and paste any relevant code into code block tags.

Comment: Are you sure those UIDs exist?  It’s not an error to try to access the flags of a non-existent message, just nothing happens.

Comment: yes , those UIDs are present and i checked about it